# Gitflow merge strategy, merge commit, squash or rebase?

Tags: git, merge, version-control, git-flow

We use the gitflow branching strategy at work and I'm curious as to what would be the best merge strategy when merging pull requests?

Up until now we have exclusively used the typical merge commit but squash merge looks appealing as it would produce a cleaner commit history.

With that said we have tried it in the past but gave up because from what I can remember,  github started having issues with the commit markers and it got confused, thinking work wasn't in the target branch when it was.

As for rebase, admittedly after 20years of development work, I still don't understand how it works.

So is there a preferred merge strategy for gitflow?

Comment: Git Flow is very explicit about using true merges when merging feature branches.

Comment: @Guildenstern what does it mean by "true merge"? Merge commit?

Comment: Yes. A merge commit with two or more parents.